# Error when referencing color declared in imported custom class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a number of custom colors that I need to use in a couple of a different classes in my program, so I have created a separate class where the colors are defined.

I have imported the class with the colors into the class where I need to use them, but when trying to then reference the colors declared in that class, the error 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference'. However, I am unsure why this error is thrown up and how to correct it?

Here's my code:

```
Public Class CustomColorScheme
Public CustomOrange As Color = color.FromArgb(232, 67, 12)
Public CustomBlue As Color = color.FromArgb(11, 219, 232)
End Class

Public Class Form1
Imports WindowsApplication1.CustomColorScheme

Sub Main()
Me.BackColor=CustomBlue
End Main

End Class
```

Comment: Looks like you're another victim of not having Option Strict On.  declare the colors as color.  Option Strict would have caught that and saved you some big headaches.  Using Shared is good and also ReadOnly so that you don't accidentally change it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the colors are declared as colors in the actual code (Code on a different computer and thus typed up incorrectly) but using shared has sorted the problem anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Shared keyword on your colors.

```
Public Class CustomColorScheme
  Public Shared CustomOrange As Color = Color.FromArgb(232, 67, 12)
  Public Shared CustomBlue As Color = Color.FromArgb(11, 219, 232)
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Me.BackColor = CustomColorScheme.CustomBlue
```